# Calling a SOAP Web Service Function

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

I am trying to use a web service to save data. The web service URL is something like:

http://example.com/webservice1/order.asmx

When I want to save an order, I will send a SOAP Envelope and have to call the function `saveorder`. How can I specify in ColdFusion that I want to call this function?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `cfhttp` and build up your SOAP Envelope and pass it through with your `cfhttp` request.

This is something I wrote some time ago:

```
<cfscript>
savecontent variable="local.sSoap" { 
    WriteOutput("
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                <soap:Body>
                    #arguments.sData#
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        "); 
}
</cfscript>
<cfhttp url="https://apiconnector.com/API.asmx" method="post" result="httpResponse">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://apiconnector.com/#arguments.sMethod#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim( local.sSOAP )#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

You'll obviously have to make changes to suit your own needs, but the gist is there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. can you please help to understand
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://apiconnector.com/#arguments.sMethod#"/>
will i not specify the "API.asmx" in before action name?

Comment: it depends on the webservice as far as i know.  so for this thing i wrote, at the time my webservice took a method exactly like: `CreateContact` which judging from what you have written is similar to yours.  You'll really have to consult your providers documentation.

Comment: Thank again what i wanted to ask is will i call the method like
value="http://apiconnector.com/saveorder"/>
OR
value="http://apiconnector.com/API.asmx/saveorder"/>

Comment: I would say the former, but it really does depend on your provider.  Hopefully it's sandboxed and you'll be able to test it without much consequence